# Odd behaviour of inline math and display before a footnote, but ok after a footnote

Tags: math-mode, displaystyle

I am puzzled with this strange behavior of math display in my file:

[image: Odd behaviour]

This is the latex file compiled with LuaLatex:

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\babelposthyphenation{portuguese}{.=.}{
    {},
    { no = -, pre = -, post = -, data = 1 },
    {}
}
\babelprovide[transforms = hyphen.repeat]{portuguese}
\addto\captionsportuguese{% Substitui ``Conteudo'' por ``Índice''
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apêndices}%
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apêndices}%
\renewcommand\bibname{Referências Bibliográficas}%
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}
}


%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{mate-ma-tica re-cu-pe-rar pres-su-pos-to jamovi Krus-kal-Wallis Wilco-xon-Mann-Whitney}
%--------------------------------------
% Para usar fontes do Windows
% as fonts tem de estar instaladas em c:\windows\fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.15] {Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setsansfont {MyriadPro-BoldSemiCn} %{MyriadPro-SemiCn} %{Lato}{MyriadPro-SemiboldSemiCn}
%\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

% para passar a fonte das formulas para EB Garamond
%\setmainfont{EB Garamond}%You should have installed the font
%\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={7,9}]%Use StylisticSet that you like
%%ou
%%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{fix-cm}% just to avoid some spurious messages
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath} %loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol} % multiplas colunas para os exercicios
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim} % para adicionar chavetas em tabelas

% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\definecolor{gray70}{gray}{0.70}
\definecolor{gray25}{gray}{0.25}
\definecolor{gray50}{gray}{0.50}
\definecolor{gray25}{RGB}{35, 140, 255}
\definecolor{gray70}{RGB}{125, 185, 250}
%\newcommand\bluebf[1]{\textcolor{gray70}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.1,BoldFeatures={Colour=gray70}] {Adobe Garamond Pro}

% Set formats for each heading level - rm, sf, tt,md, bf, up, it, sl, sc
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\mdseries\color{gray70}}
{\chaptertitlename\huge\bfseries~\thechapter}{20pt}
{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{gray25}\uppercase}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{120pt}  %controls vertical margins on title

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\color{gray25}}
  {\thesection.}{0.4em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\color{gray25}}
  {\thesubsection.}{0.4em}{}
  \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\itshape\color{gray25}}
  {\thesubsubsection.}{0.4em}{}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

% Drop Cap
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2 #3 {%
    \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
    \StrLeft{#3}{1}[\jpmd@temp]%
    \lettrine[lines=2, findent=1pt, nindent=1pt, slope=4pt]{\jpmd@temp}{\@gobble#3}\ }
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\textnormal} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{gray70} \bfseries}
\makeatother

%Define o paper size
\usepackage[paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=230mm, margin=15mm, bottom=20mm, top=30mm, headsep=15mm,footskip=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdftex]{crop}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\color{gray70}\uppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\color{gray70}\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
\thechapter.%
\ #1}}{}}

% pacotes para várias coisas\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercícios}[section]

\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[page,toc,titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % rotating contents
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[hidelinks, linktocpage=true, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} % para adicionar linhas às tabelas
% necessário para o ambiente dos exemplos
%\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math} % conflits with cooljaz math
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt} % floating images nas Tabs.tex
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% only needed for the arrow tip stealth'
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\ttfamily}}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
% Trocar a fonte dos graficosTikz para Helvetica Light
\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.9]{HELVETICALT_0.TTF}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\ttfamily}}}
\usepackage{pstricks}    %for embedding pspicture.
\usepackage{pst-func,amsmath,xfp,pst-tree} %for calculations and normal functions
% Trocar a fonte dos graficos PStricks para Helvetica Light
\renewcommand{\pshlabel}[1]{\ttfamily #1}% for x-axis
\renewcommand{\psvlabel}[1]{\ttfamily #1}% for y-axis
%para centrar o icon com a o cabeçalho da box
\newcommand{\vcenteredinclude}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=.75]{#1}}%
\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}

% makes gray box around text (precisa do pacakge tikz)
%\newcommand\mybox[2][fill=gray!20]{%
\newcommand\mybox[2][fill=gray70!20]{%
    \tikz[baseline]\node[%
    inner ysep=0pt, 
    inner xsep=2pt, 
    anchor=text, 
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners=0.2mm,
    #1] {\strut#2};%
}

\newcommand*{\Fbox}[1]{\fbox{\strut #1}}    

\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}
\def\mmybox#1{\leavevmode \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \dimen0=\wd0 \edef\posxA{\expandafter\ignorept\the\dimen0 \space}%
   \hbox{\kern3pt\pdfliteral{q .9 g .9 G .9963 0 0 .9963 0 0 cm 1 j 1 J 6 w
                             0 0 m 0 5 l \posxA 5 l \posxA 0 l 0 0 l B Q}%
         \box0 \kern3pt}%
}
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}

% define ambimente de exemplos
\makeatletter
\crefformat{tcb@cnt@Exemplo}{exemplo~#2#1#3}
\Crefformat{tcb@cnt@Exemplo}{Exemplo~#2#1#3}
\makeatother
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{exemplo}{\, Exemplo}%
{ % frame stuff
    breakable,
    arc=40mm,
    size=normal,
    enhanced,%frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=gray70,
    colback=white,colbacklower=white,
    borderline={0.01mm}{0.01mm}{gray70!10},
    % margens da frame
    top=0.3cm,left=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
    % title stuff
    %attach boxed title to top left={yshift=0mm,xshift=-0mm},
    %boxsep=2mm,
    lefttitle=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=0.1cm,
    coltitle=gray70,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=gray70!10,
    %boxed title style={boxrule=.0pt,sharp corners}
    rounded corners,
    %borderline=0.1pt,
    lifted shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}{gray25!70!white},
    overlay={\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=-1pt, xshift=-11pt] at (frame.north west)                
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{pencilblue}}; }
    }{ex}
   
      
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\usepackage{amsmath} loaded by mathtools

% Environment for hand resolution

\newfontfamily\cooljazz[NFSSFamily=cooljazz,BoldFont={Boogaloo Regular},Scale=0.85,Ligatures=TeX]{cooljazz}
\usepackage[subdued, defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\MTfamily{cooljazz}
\Mathastext[cooljazz]

\newenvironment{coolj}{

    \MTversion{cooljazz}\MTdonotfixfonts
    \setmainfont{cooljazz}[Scale = .8, Extension = .ttf ]
    % adjust some additional glyphs
    \Umathchardef\prod 1 \symmtoperatorfont `∏\relax % mathop
    \Umathchardef\sum  1 \symmtoperatorfont `∑\relax % mathop
    \Umathchardef\in   3 \symmtoperatorfont `∈\relax %
    \Umathchardef\int  1 \symmtoperatorfont `∫\relax % mathop
    \Umathchardef\neq  3 \symmtoperatorfont `≠\relax % mathrel
    %\Umathchardef\sqrt  1 \symmtoperatorfont `√\relax % mathrel
    \Umathchardef\mu  1 \symmtoperatorfont `μ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\sigma 1 \symmtoperatorfont `σ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\gamma 1 \symmtoperatorfont `γ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\beta 1 \symmtoperatorfont `β\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\epsilon 1 \symmtoperatorfont `ε\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\eta 1 \symmtoperatorfont `η\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\alpha 1 \symmtoperatorfont `α\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\theta 1 \symmtoperatorfont `θ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\rho 1 \symmtoperatorfont `ρ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\phi 1 \symmtoperatorfont `ϕ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\sim 1 \symmtoperatorfont `~\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\chi 1 \symmtoperatorfont `χ\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\ge 1 \symmtoperatorfont `≥\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\le 1 \symmtoperatorfont `≤\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\exists 1 \symmtoperatorfont `∃\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\pm 1 \symmtoperatorfont `±\relax % greek
    \Umathchardef\forall1 \symmtoperatorfont `∀\relax % greek
    %
}{\par}

% Set TexaTI environment
\newfontfamily{\TIkeys}{TI84KEYSYMBOLS.TTF}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\tikeys}{\TIkeys}
%\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}[Scale = .90]
\newfontfamily{\CMU}{CMU Typewriter Text}[Scale = 1]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\cmutext}{\CMU}
\newfontfamily{\TItext}{TI-83-PLUS-REGULAR.ttf}[Scale=0.7] 
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\titext}{\TItext}
% para alinhar os triangulos do ambiente TI84
\newcommand{\tri}{\raisebox{.15 em}{\tiny$\blacktriangleright$}}
\newfontfamily{\MSS}{Microsoft Sans Serif}[Scale = .85]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\jmvtext}{\MSS}

\newfontfamily{\hlv}{Helvetica-Light}[Scale = .85]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\hlvtext}{\hlv}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{Ti84}{\, Ti84}%
{ % frame stuff
    breakable,
    arc=40mm,
    size=normal,
    enhanced,%frame empty,interior empty,
colframe=gray70,
colback=white,colbacklower=white,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{gray70!10},
% margens da frame
top=0.3cm,left=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
% title stuff
%attach boxed title to top left={yshift=0mm,xshift=-0mm},
%boxsep=2mm,
lefttitle=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=0.1cm,
coltitle=gray70,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=gray70!10,
%boxed title style={boxrule=.0pt,sharp corners}
rounded corners,
%borderline=0.1pt,
lifted shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}{gray25!70!white},
    overlay={\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=-1pt, xshift=-11pt] at (frame.north west)  {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{maquinablue}}; }
    }{ex}

%Summary Environment
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = chapter]{resumo}{\, \sffamily Resumo}%
{ % frame stuff
    %breakable,
    arc=40mm,
    size=normal,
    enhanced,%frame empty,interior empty,
colframe=gray25,
colback=gray70!10,colbacklower=white,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{gray70!10},
% margens da frame
top=0.3cm,left=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
% title stuff
%attach boxed title to top left={yshift=0mm,xshift=-0mm},
%boxsep=2mm,
lefttitle=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=0.1cm,
coltitle=gray25,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=gray25!25,
%boxed title style={boxrule=.0pt,sharp corners}
rounded corners,
%borderline=0.1pt,
lifted shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}{gray25!70!white},
    overlay={\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=-2pt, xshift=-11pt] at (frame.north west) {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{bulbblue}}; }
    }{res}
\newenvironment{tabresumo}{
\small
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}[Scale=.9,BoldFont={Myriad Pro Bold}]
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\setmathfont[math-style=upright,range={up/{Latin,latin,num, italic}},Scale=0.85]{helvetica.otf}
%\setmathfont[Scale=0.9] {latinmodern-math.otf}%{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
%\DeclareMathSizes{9}{8.5}{7}{5}  % o primeiro valor é o fontsize do texto, o segundo é o fontsize da font math, o 3º do subscripto e o 4º do subsubscripto.
}{\par} 

% jamov environment
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = section]{jamovi}{\, \cmutext{jamovi}}%
{ % frame stuff
    breakable,
    arc=40mm,
    size=normal,
    enhanced,%frame empty,interior empty,
colframe=gray70,
colback=white,colbacklower=white,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{gray70!10},
% margens da frame
top=0.3cm,left=0.2cm,bottom=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,
% title stuff
%attach boxed title to top left={yshift=0mm,xshift=-0mm},
%boxsep=2mm,
lefttitle=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm,bottomtitle=0.1cm,
coltitle=gray70,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colbacktitle=gray70!10,
%boxed title style={boxrule=.0pt,sharp corners}
rounded corners,
%borderline=0.1pt,
lifted shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}{gray25!70!white},
    overlay={\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=-1pt, xshift=-11pt] at (frame.north west)  {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{computerblue}}; }
}{exjmv}

% to center figures and tables without \centering
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

% for inline figures:
\usepackage{graphicx,calc,scalerel}
\newcommand*\inlinegraphics[1]{%
    \raisebox{0\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*\inlinefig[1]{%
    \scalerel*{\includegraphics{#1}}{D}%
}

% To reference chapters
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

% Style for reports in the results examples
\def\relat#1{
    \begin{quote}
        \hspace*{-0.40cm}\raisebox{-1.2ex}{\color{lightgray}\huge \textbf{``}}{#1}
\end{quote} }


\newcommand*{\Comb}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}} % defines Combinations
\newcommand{\mybar}[3]{% makes extra bar
\mathrlap{\hspace{#2}\overline{\scalebox{#1}[1]{\phantom{\ensuremath{#3}}}}}\ensuremath{#3}
}

%For bibliogtaphy
\usepackage{natbib}

% add dumb text
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{siunitx} % aligns numbers by decimal separator
\newcolumntype{d}{S[table-format=6.4]}

%font dos urls
%\urlstyle{tt}
\def\UrlFont{\CMU}
%para obter os Z e N dos numeros naturais
%\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
%\setmathfont[range={"211-"2124}]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

% Main document with subchapter
% \usepackage{subfiles} % está no Book.tex

\newfontfamily\DejaSans{DejaVu Sans} % gets emoticons
```

If I don't use the premable if works as suppoded. So it must be some setting I have in the `\usepackage{xxx}`. But I can figure it out.

Any idea of what may be causing this odd behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: note you should not use `$$` in latex and never have a blank line before a display (unrelated to your issue though)

Comment: Please provide an example here that does not use external links. we can not run `\documentclass[../Book.tex]{subfiles}`  do you need a multi-file subfiles example to demonstrate an issue with footnotes?

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. Include the huge preamble (it's for a book) in the MWE...

Comment: Then reduce it down so it only shows your problem. This is an important debugging tool. We are not going to debug a massive preamble for you. Make a new document with this preamble, and you sample text and start removing stuff, if you can remove it, recompile and the problem is still there, is it was probably irrelevant. Repeat. This way you often end up figuring out the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks @daleif. Yes, .... thats the way, but I was wondering if someone had the problem before. After using a footnote environment it works...

Comment: you have not provided a file that shows the problem. just provided a very long list of unrelated code including many lines that do nothing why load enumitem, xstring, .. twice?  do you need `\usepackage{wrapfig}` to show the problem, if not why is it in the example?

Comment: Post a small complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` preferably using standard fonts that  produces `X_i` with X in roman not math italic. Then we can debug.

Comment: As I said, I can't figure it out. The preamble is actually a sty file, that  I load... But I just need to figure out each library is causing the conflict, that disappears after evoking a footnote... I was hoping someone had that problem before....

Comment: why can you not make an example? Just make a document that just makes the text you show in the image, using the preamble you posted, then delete each package, checking the problem still occurs, then when you can delete no more post your test file. That is what MWE means. Minimal but an example of the problem.

Comment: working on that

Comment: So, working as you suggested, I was able to find the problem with the `nicematrix` package.  Commenting `%\usepackage{nicematrix}` did stop the strange behaviour for the inline and display math. The question now is why? Why does a footnote breaks the nice matrix effect.... Maybe the author fpantigny@wanadoo.fr could have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Package `nicematrix`is required to this figure text:
[image]

Moving `nicematrix`before the `mathfont` declarations did the trick.